# Excel Macro Saves as PDF

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I have a Macro that applies some filters and then exports certain columns as a PDF file, currently the Macro saves the PDF in the same folder as the Excel file but I would like it to ask me where I want to save the file instead, is this possible?

Any help much appreciated! :)

```
Sub FilterSaveCases()
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
.LeftHeader = "&B& &20 Doff Stock : " & Format(Now, " ddmmyyyy")
    On Error Resume Next
    Columns("H:H").AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    
    Columns("H:H").AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("H:H").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">1"
    Columns("C:O").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Columns("P:P").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    ActiveSheet.Pictures("Picture 1").Visible = False

  Dim Nm As String
  Dim Rng As Range
  
  Set Rng = Range("A1:P198")
  Nm = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
  Nm = Left(Nm, InStrRev(Nm, ".") - 1) & Format(Now, " ddmmyyyy") & ".pdf"
  
  Rng.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=Nm, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=True, OpenAfterPublish:=True

ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    Columns("C:O").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Columns("M:M").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Columns("P:P").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ActiveSheet.Pictures("Picture 1").Visible = True

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Add this to your code. It will ask the user to select a location to save the file.

```
Sub download_location()
    Dim user As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Dim getfolder As String
    user = Application.UserName
    
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    getfolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing


'do something here

End Sub
```